# VB.NET button compute then summary

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a program that if I click the `button5(summary)` it will not show the summary report until I first click `button1(compute)`.  How do I do this?

Relevant Code:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

   If Not IsNumeric(TextBox6.Text) Or _
       Not IsNumeric(TextBox7.Text) Or _
       Not IsNumeric(TextBox8.Text) Or _
       Not IsNumeric(TextBox9.Text) Then
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input", "Warning", _
       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
   ElseIf 99 >= TextBox6.Text Or _
       99 >= TextBox7.Text Or _
       99 >= TextBox8.Text Or _
       99 >= TextBox9.Text Then
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid Amount", "Warning", _
       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
   Else
     Form5.Show()
     Me.Hide()
     Form5.Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text
     Form5.Label5.Text = TextBox2.Text
     Form5.Label7.Text = TextBox3.Text
     Form5.Label9.Text = ComboBox1.Text
     Form5.Label11.Text = TextBox4.Text
     Form5.Label13.Text = ComboBox2.Text
     Form5.Label15.Text = Label27.Text
     Form5.Label22.Text = Label14.Text
     Form5.Label17.Text = Label22.Text
     Form5.Label19.Text = Label25.Text
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you think it might be a good idea not to leave everything with default names? A couple months from now what's `Label14` going to mean?

Comment: I am just a beginners in VB.NET and its a school project but i dont know what you mean about label14???

Comment: What @C.Lang means is that `Label14` is not a descriptive name and that you should strive to make names more contextual (i.e., `labelUsersFirstName` instead of `Label14`). The reasoning behind this is for **when** you are revisiting your code a couple of months or years from now, you'll have a much better idea of what that label represents.

Comment: Perfect! If you're a beginner you won't have to worry about developing bad habits. If it is a school project and your instructor has not already warned/taught you to *always* use self descriptive identifiers for your variables - be sceptical. For instance a string that said "Hello World" might be named `helloWorldText`. Or anything other than the name applied by the IDE. This is what I mean => `Form5.Label22.Text = Label14.Text`.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Button1_Click()` at the start of your `Button5_Click` handler?

Comment: the professor said to us that we must not change the labels name for now and he is strick so if he see us change the label name its a minus for us

Comment: how to call?? the button

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your `Button1_Click()` handler at the start of your `Button5_Click` handler:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Button1_Click() 'Call the handler at the start of your subroutine

    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox6.Text) Or Not IsNumeric(TextBox7.Text) Or Not IsNumeric(TextBox8.Text) Or Not IsNumeric(TextBox9.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

    ElseIf 99 >= TextBox6.Text Or 99 >= TextBox7.Text Or 99 >= TextBox8.Text Or 99 >= TextBox9.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Amount", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)



    Else
        Form5.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        Form5.Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text
        Form5.Label5.Text = TextBox2.Text
        Form5.Label7.Text = TextBox3.Text
        Form5.Label9.Text = ComboBox1.Text
        Form5.Label11.Text = TextBox4.Text
        Form5.Label13.Text = ComboBox2.Text
        Form5.Label15.Text = Label27.Text
        Form5.Label22.Text = Label14.Text
        Form5.Label17.Text = Label22.Text
        Form5.Label19.Text = Label25.Text

    End If
End Sub
```

Assuming `Button1_Click()` handles the "compute" portion, this should work for you.

An easier way to write this is to write subroutines that are contextually-named and then call those routines from your click handlers.

Example:

```
Private Sub Compute()
    'Do computations
    'Use a function instead of a sub if you need to return a value.
End Sub

Private Sub Summarize()
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox6.Text) Or Not IsNumeric(TextBox7.Text) Or Not IsNumeric(TextBox8.Text) Or Not IsNumeric(TextBox9.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    ElseIf 99 >= TextBox6.Text Or 99 >= TextBox7.Text Or 99 >= TextBox8.Text Or 99 >= TextBox9.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Amount", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    Else
        Form5.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        Form5.Label3.Text = TextBox1.Text
        Form5.Label5.Text = TextBox2.Text
        Form5.Label7.Text = TextBox3.Text
        Form5.Label9.Text = ComboBox1.Text
        Form5.Label11.Text = TextBox4.Text
        Form5.Label13.Text = ComboBox2.Text
        Form5.Label15.Text = Label27.Text
        Form5.Label22.Text = Label14.Text
        Form5.Label17.Text = Label22.Text
        Form5.Label19.Text = Label25.Text

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Compute() 'Call compute subroutine
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Compute()   'Call compute subroutine
    Summarize() 'Call summarize subroutine
End Sub
```